# Why the 7 Apples?

Tags: situation, humor

A doctor and a bus driver are both in love with the same woman, a girl named Sarah. The bus driver had to go on a long bus trip that would last a week. Before he left, he gave Sarah seven apples. Why?

Comment: It looks like [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/63998/12114) is the first answer, if that is a tie-breaker when it comes to accepting an answer.

Comment: I'm sure to laugh any day now

Comment: How do you like them apples?

Comment: jkl3699, please see comments [here](//puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/63998).

Comment: I appreciate the simplicity of this puzzle. But it would have been better if the profession of both parties were not mentioned in the question. It would have been fun to see how many people correctly guesses about the second party being a Doctor.

Comment: Because he loves her and wants her to stay healthy :)

Comment: Thank you @jkl3699 for accepting my answer!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Because

> An apple a day keeps the doctor away so he gave 7 apple for 7 days.

Comment: This duplicate answer is 12 seconds older, so it deserves to be marked as the correct one.

Comment: @jkl3699 look back over the answers?

Comment: @NL628, notifications work only for users that had already appeared in this thread. As jkl3699 neither is an author of the current answer, nor has commented it before, he won't be notified with a `@jkl3699`-containing comment.

Comment: @PaigeMeinke, notifications work only for users that had already appeared in this thread. As jkl3699 neither is an author of the current answer, nor has commented it before, he won't be notified with a `@jkl3699`-containing comment.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to give the tick to the FIRST answerer, when both answers appeared so close together. I think it's up to the OP to pick the better answer; however, in my opinion, this answer betters answers the question because it explains _why_ 7 apples

Answer (score 39):

Easy

> An apple a day keeps the doctor away.

Comment: +1 for awesomeness

Answer (score 14):

because

> it is a well known fact that an apple a day keeps the doctor away - which is obviously what this bus driver wants!

Comment: Actually, I think JonMark's is the oldest

Comment: @North check out the exact times by hovering over the time.

Comment: @north; I think I thought it quicker, but I was out-typed